Phantom unread review numbers
This has happened so many times over a very long period that I couldn't believe it's a browser cache or SE bug anymore - the 'unread' review number is positive but when I click into the lists, all the sub-items ('first post', 'close votes', etc.) are zero. Am I overlooking somewhere?
I am asking this question here because it doesn't repro on other SE sites.

It does happen on other sites (e.g.); last I heard its apparently working as designed.

@Semaphore I see, thanks.
